# SelectMany triggers subscription while Select does not

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I do not understand in the example below why Select does not trigger the subscription while SelectMany does.  This example is based off of something I am working on but reduced to as simple as I can get it so that the issue is reproducible.

When I hit the button, `_subject.OnNext` is called.  The ViewModel is subscribed to `_subject` and calls `GetObservable()` which returns an `IObservable<Unit>`.  At this point `Debug.WriteLine("SUBSCRIBED");` is not hit in `GetObservable()`.

However, if I change `_subject.Select(_ => GetObservable()).Subscribe();` to `_subject.SelectMany(_ => GetObservable()).Subscribe();` the debug line is hit.

How is the subscription happening with SelectMany and not with Select?  My understanding is that with Observable.Create, the specified delegate will be executed anytime a subscription is made.  I just don't see where the subscription is being made with SelectMany.

View:

```
<Window x:Class="Rxtest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Rxtest"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:ViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Rxtest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Rxtest
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private ICommand _saveCommand;
        private Subject<int> _subject = new Subject<int>();

        public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_saveCommand == null)
                {
                    _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        p => true,
                        p => DoSomeImportantMethod());
                }
                return _saveCommand;
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            _subject.Select(_ => GetObservable()).Subscribe();

        }        

        private void DoSomeImportantMethod()
        {
            _subject.OnNext(1);
        }

        private IObservable<Unit> GetObservable()
        {
            return Observable.Create<Unit>(observer =>
            {
                observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                Debug.WriteLine("SUBSCRIBED");
                return Disposable.Empty;
            });
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
        {
            _canExecute = canExecute;
            _execute = execute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s all in the typing. `.Select` here is returning a double observable, `IObservable<IObservable<Unit>>`. The subscribe call subscribes to the outer observable, but your Debug statement only exists on the inner observable. The inner observable remains unsubscribed to.

`.SelectMany` flattens the double observable into a simple `IObservable<Unit>` where your Debug statement will fire.